# How to find the core context of a sentence

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Lets consider a couple of sentence  like

```
Jason live California 

I live in California

Jason and Robert are friend the both live in California
```

Both of the above sentences are about California

By using `nltk` how can I extract *California* from above sentences

I am kind of new in `nlp` any help will be highly appreciated .

Comment: live is also common,, if you use nltk , you will get "live" also.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want nltk library to fetch only California from all the sentence

You can use simple code to fetch the single word

But if you want to fetch the places from the sentence then use this :-

pip install geotext

is all it takes to install this library. The usage is as simple as:

from geotext import GeoText
places = GeoText("London is a great city")
places.cities
gives the result 'London'

The list of cities covered in this library is not extensive but it has a good list.